# PHP functions not working in bitcoin JSON-RPC version 16 (bitcoin-cli is working properly)

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, json-rpc, php, bitcoin-cli

> **Trying to implement Bitcoin JSON-RPC using Digital Ocean Ubuntu using bitcoin version 16.**

Here is my php code

```
<?php

require_once('easybitcoin.php');

$bitcoin = new Bitcoin('someusername', 'somepassword');

print_r($bitcoin);

//print_r($bitcoin->getwalletinfo()());

$getinfo = $bitcoin->getblockchaininfo();

print_r($getinfo);

?>
```

> **Output**
>
> Bitcoin Object ( [username:Bitcoin:private] => someusername
>   [password:Bitcoin:private] => somepassword [proto:Bitcoin:private] =>
>   http [host:Bitcoin:private] => localhost [port:Bitcoin:private] =>
>   8332 [url:Bitcoin:private] => [CACertificate:Bitcoin:private] =>
>   [status] => [error] => [raw_response] => [response] =>
>   [id:Bitcoin:private] => 0 )
>
> **Giving error HTTP ERROR 500**

I'm not much php aware, I tried enabling error reporting in php.ini but not getting errorlog.

Here is my **bitcoin.conf**

```
rpcuser=someusername
rpcpassword=somepassword
prune=600
maxconnections=12
maxuploadtarget=20
daemon=1
server=1
keypool=10000
```

Bitcoin server is fully synced in prune mode, up & running.bitcoin-cli properly working. If anyone have new working php-bitcoind examples, please share on vd30992@gmail.com

[image: working bitcoin-cli]

> Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Working JSON-RPC from php. Reamined Ubuntu server configration causing
>   problems.

Main thing ,allow 8332 port using `sudo ufw allow 8332`

Easybitcoin.php based on cURL. So install `apt-get install php5-curl`

Following post helped:

[JSON RPC call from webpage to Bitcoin Core](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/51022/json-rpc-call-from-webpage-to-bitcoin-core?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

`getinfo` was removed from Bitcoin Core 0.16. Use `getblockchaininfo`, `getnetworkinfo`, `getmininginfo`, or `getwalletinfo` depending on what you actually need. A mapping of each `getinfo` field to its replacement can be found here: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/release-notes/release-notes-0.14.0.md#getinfo-deprecated

Comment: so https://github.com/aceat64/EasyBitcoin-PHP this repo is useless then? we are unable to use it? if yes then is any alternative? Thanks

Comment: You can just replace the `getinfo()` calls to the appropriate replacement.

Comment: Please see updated question. if you got any clue, kindly tell me where I mistaken. Thanks for your valuable time.